# Plotting an implicit function

Tags: plotting

Suppose I am given an equation of the following form: $f(x,y)=0$. I would like to find $y$ as a function of $x$. i.e. find the function $y=y(x)$. In general, it is impossible to find a closed-form solution. I can use ContourPlot to visualize the solution. Now, suppose I would like to plot a function $z=g(y(x))$ in terms of $x$. How can I do this in Mathematica?

Comment: Is $y$ a function of $x$ in general?  Or can $f$ be something like $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$? People here generally like users to post a minimal working example in *Mathematica* code. It makes it convenient for them to copy-paste it and test their ideas. It's more likely you will get someone to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's generic approach, if you can pick a initial point:

```
Block[{f, g, a, b, x0, y0 ics},
 (* set up problem *)
 f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 - 1;
 g[y_] := Sin[Pi y];
 a = -1;
 b = 1;
 {x0, y0} = {0, 1};
 
 (* generic solution *)
 ics = {y[x0] == y0, z[x0] == g[y0]};
 ListLinePlot@
  NDSolveValue[{D[z[x] == g[y[x]], x], D[f[x, y[x]] == 0, x], ics}, 
   z, {x, a, b}]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Michael E2 provide an example.

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 - 1;
g[t_] := Sin[Pi*t];
ParametricPlot[{x, g[y]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, u, v}, f[u, v]], Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Red, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.01], PlotPoints -> 80, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Another way is use `ParametricRegion`.

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 - 1;
g[t_] := Sin[Pi*t];
RegionPlot[
 DiscretizeRegion[ParametricRegion[{{x, g[y]}, f[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}],
   MaxCellMeasure -> {Length -> 0.01}]]
```

[image]